# Eclipse. Can not open with Android Layout Editor

Tags: android

I wonder, everytime I try to open the main.xml file in the res/layout directory, eclipse stop responding. The problem does not occur if I open the file by right clicking it and select other method than Android Layout Editor.

I've searched through the net, and some say that by updatin the java version, the problem is gone. I've installed JDK 6u24, and set my Eclispe to use that editor (Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs). But still I could not open the main.xml with Android Layout Editor. I wonder why?

I'm using Eclipse Helios and ADT 8.0.1.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest ADT should help.